# LESS String extrapolation with WP-Less available?

Tags: wordpress, less, mixins

I'm trying to compile Twitter Bootstrap in LESS with [WP-Less](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-less/) in Wordpress.
When compiling, i get a parse error when i' face to a String Extrapolation as described in [this link](http://lesscss.org/#-mixins)

It's decribed like that:

**String interpolation**

*Variables can be embeded inside strings in a similar way to ruby or PHP, with the @{name} construct:*

```
@base-url: "http://assets.fnord.com";
background-image: url("@{base-url}/images/bg.png");
```

and in mixins.less, my error come from:

```
      (~".span@{index}") { .span(@index); }
```

I've already post a question in the support section. But i'd like to see that String Extrapolation is not supported.

Do you have any idea ??

Best regards

S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found something interesting..

WP-Less is based on lessphp.. but the plugin include lessphp **v0.3.1**.

By changing it by lessphp **v0.3.5** ([download page](http://leafo.net/lessphp/#download)), there is no more error message.

I don't say that every is ok to add Twitter Bootstrap LESS version in Wordpress, but my investigations are going on..

Closed topic for me.

Best regards

S.